# How to handle a token key in a website made with django, django-rest-auth, and react?

Tags: django, reactjs, token, django-rest-auth

First of all, I am pretty new to working with Rest APIs and tokens, I have learned the basics of Django and React and I've kinda made some projects using those, so I'm giving a shot at making a website with both of them.

Since, registering is simple with django-rest-auth, it's been handled with just POSTING the user data. However, when making a login, the token was returned and I simply do not know how to handle it. I have searched many articles about tokens, but they were all about JWT which returns an access token and a refresh token. However, django-rest-auth returns a single token and I saved it inside a cookie using a 'universal-cookie' in React. Since I'm making an e-commerce website, and I do want to add some functionality to the website by enabling the users to change their email, last name, first name and username, I do need to know the username of the account as it is unique.

So, I am wondering if it would be alright and a good practice to save the username inside a cookie, again using a universal-cookie. It'd also be appreciated if someone shows me a good article about "what to do with a token" or how to utilize it because I have little to none knowledge about it.

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const csrftoken = getCookie("csrf");
const url = "http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/";

const cookies = new Cookies();
await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }, 
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password,
  }),
}).then((response) => {
  setResponseCode(response.status);
  response.json().then((key) => {
    cookies.set("token", key.key);
    setIsClicked(true);
  });
});
};`
```

Here is how I've been storing the token I get, and using it from navbar or other react components to check if the user has been logged in or not.